# Xcode version transfer

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have an application in Xcode 6. However, I recently upgraded to Xcode 7 beta, but I still have the Xcode 6 software. I opened on of my applications in Xcode 6 (with Xcode 6), and now I have an error. I believe the error is caused by having the code upgraded to Xcode 7, but I am not positive. Here is my error:

Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 11

It is not showing me to a specific line of code, and I am not sure exactly how to fix this. Does anyone know how?

Comment: Xcode 7 only supports Swift 2.0. This means you cannot have a single project with Swift code that can be opened in both Xcode 6 & 7. However, if you need to migrate you project back to Xcode 6.4 from 7, this is indeed possible. The answer by javivl worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode 7 uses Swift 2.0, which is not supported by Xcode 6.  If you migrated your Swift code, you must either open it in Xcode 7 from now on, revert (if you used git or something similar), or manually convert back to Swift 1.2.

Comment: How should I convert it to Xcode 7? Should I create the objects again in Main.storyboard, copy the code, connect the links, and fix the errors? Or is there an easier way?

Comment: Just as @ILikeTau says, use the tool, keep a copy of the old project just in case.

Answer (score 1):

It did work for me with the: Product -> Clean

Comment: Had the same problem after downgrading and resolved it by cleaning my projects. I had already reverted changes made by Xcode when migrating to swift 2.0, which did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and to solve it I did download the Xcode command line tools for the Xcode 6.4 I use, from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/. Installed, and then I did a Product -> Clean in Xcode with my project too.

I had not updated my Swift-app to Swift 2.0, so if you did that this won't work!

Also, found somewhere that running *xcode-select --install* in the terminal should help - but I'm not sure what version is downloaded, so I ran the download as a mentioned above...

Comment: Sorry but I had already made changes to fit Xcode 7. I'm still getting the error though...